# Center a Div in a Div with two right floats CSS

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have a minor issue here.  I'd like to center the red div and have the two green divs float to the right.  The two right divs appear to drop down?

http://jsbin.com/ewihuh/1/edit

HTML

```
<div class="headertop">
 <div class="centerblock">Centered</div>
 <div class="right1">right 1</div>
 <div class="right2">right 2</div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.headertop {
 width:100%;
 height:30px;
 background:black;
}

.centerblock {
 color:white;
 text-align:center;
 background:red;
 width: 200px;
 margin: 0px auto;
}

.right1, .right2 {
 color:white;
 float:right; 
 width:100px;
 background:green;
}
```

Comment: Wrap your `right1` and `right2` into a `div` may make life easier: http://jsbin.com/ewihuh/3/edit

Comment: @Passerby perfect.  How can I have the two right floats be next to each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/Y9597/10/)

Hi **now change** to `your html code` and some change to `css`

**Css**

```
  .headertop {
    width:100%;
    background:black;
    text-align:center;
}
.centerblock {
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    background:red;
    width: 200px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.right1, .right2{
    color:white;
    float:right;
    width:100px;
    background:green;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="headertop">
    <div class="right1">right 1</div>  
    <div class="right2">right 2</div>
    <div class="centerblock">Centered</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect!  Why the "overflow:hidden" on the parent, .headertop?

Comment: @user1100603 so sorry remove overflow:hidden;

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="headertop">
  <div class="centerblock">Centered</div>
  <div class="rights">
    <div class="right1">right 1</div>
    <div class="right2">right 2</div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .headertop {
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
  background:black;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  }

 .centerblock {
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  background:red;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }

.rights {
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 width:100px;
}

.right1, .right2 {
 color:white;
 width:50px;
 background:green;
 float:left;
 }
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/ewihuh/7/edit